# Using datetimepicker in a where clause in vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

```
 Dim con1 As OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim query As String


            Dim rs As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
            con1 = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;Password=sys;User ID=nitishok")
            con1.Open()


            query = "select * from HOLDERSDB where DOB like '" + DateTimePicker1.Value + "' "
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con1)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            rs = cmd.ExecuteReader

            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, con1)

            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds, "HOLDERSDB")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

            con1.Close()
    enter code here
```

i want rows from HOLDERS table that have DOB as datetimepicker1
The code that i have posted does not return any results.

Plz help.

Comment: can , you check data is comming in "da" object.

Comment: Check what the format of DOB filed in your database is (is something like 1/11/2012 or 1 Nov 2012 or includes time etc). Then it is better to have the same format in your DataTimePicker. Check also DateTimePicker1.Value what is returns to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming DOB is a DATE field (hopefully it is!) 
then use TO_DATE and don't try to compare date=string, otherwise your code will fail if not today then someday.

```
"select * from HOLDERSDB where dob = to_date(" + DateTimePicker1.Value + ", 'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

see here to format the return of DateTimePicker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx

make sure to format it the same way as the 2nd parameter (doesnt have to be dd-mon-yyyy as i put, Oracle supports multiple formats) in the TO_DATE function.

also you should be using bind variables and not pasting strings into the SQL anyway for performance / security reasons.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked with a little modification...

"select * from HOLDERSDB where DOB like to_date(" + DateTimePicker1.Value.Date + ", 'dd-mon-yy')

Answer (score 0):

Steps you need to take to pinpoint the problem:

- Check the value of `query`, is it correct?
- Run the query against the db manually, are results returned?
- Check `ds` object has data using `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`, greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Once I used:

```
Public Function SQLDate(p1 As Date) As String
    Return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", p1.Year, p1.Month.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c), p1.Day.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c))
End Function
```

So:

```
Debug.Print(SQLDate(DateTimePicker1.Value)) =====> 20121101
```

And in SQL query use:

```
String.Format("... WHERE DOB = '{0}'", SQLDate(DateTimePicker1.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add OleDbParameter to [cmd.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) instead of concatenating in the query. This will reduce hacking possibility and will help me insert the right type of value.

Also, I don't see why you need a like statement. Maybe you should use a normal = operator especially if DOB is a date.